# Column names changing when using as.data.frame on a list in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list that I'm trying to change to a data frame in R.  When I do this with as.data.frame it takes the name of the individual lists and adds it to the front of each column name in the new df.  Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
emp.data <- data.frame(
  emp_id = c (1:5), 
  emp_name = c("Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary"))

emp.data2 <- data.frame(
  emp_id2 = c (1:5), 
  emp_name2 = c("Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary"))

total <- list("emp.data" = emp.data, "emp.data2" = emp.data2)

total <- as.data.frame(total)
```

total now looks like:

```
  emp.data.emp_id emp.data.emp_name emp.data2.emp_id2 emp.data2.emp_name2
1               1              Rick                 1                Rick
2               2               Dan                 2                 Dan
3               3          Michelle                 3            Michelle
4               4              Ryan                 4                Ryan
5               5              Gary                 5                Gary
```

I need to keep the names of the dataframes because I use them elsewhere.  Is there anyway to make this not happen and have the column names remain unchanged?

Thanks,
Stacy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

any of the following will work:

1.

```
as.data.frame(unname(total))
  emp_id emp_name emp_id2 emp_name2
1      1     Rick       1      Rick
2      2      Dan       2       Dan
3      3 Michelle       3  Michelle
4      4     Ryan       4      Ryan
5      5     Gary       5      Gary
```

2. 

```
do.call(cbind, unname(total))
```

3. 

```
do.call(data.frame, unname(total))
```